# What are the NPC homes in swamp biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the homes that generate in the swamps called? What can you find there?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The names of the buildings? Their purposes?

Comment: Your asking multiple questions within the same question, which isn't how it is supposed to be done here. Please separate your different questions into multiple posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are called witch huts, here is the information from the wikia:

[image]

> Witch Huts generate in swamp biomes or, very, very rarely, other
> biomes. Witches can spawn inside of them. The huts consist of spruce
> Wood Planks and oak wood. Spruce wood stairs make the roof borders, 2
> fences decorate the entrance and one fence make the entrance window
> bars. Inside is a crafting table and an empty cauldron; on the
> windowsills are potted mushrooms. There's no valid way a witch can get
> back up into the hut if it falls off it.
>
> There are no chests or any
> other loot inside. It is possible, but rare, for a mushroom to
> generate inside the Hut while not potted, with the potted one still in
> place. Strangely, they are just high enough for the witches to fit in,
> but their hats are in the ceiling, making the animation look broken.
> They seem to be based on the design of Baba Yaga's hut, a witch from
> Slavic folklore who lived in a hut that walked around on giant chicken
> legs.

Source: [Witch Huts](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Generated_structures#Witch_Huts)

Comment: Oh, a sudden realization that foreign people do know about characters from my childhood tales... Logical and reasonable, but I've just failed to think of it ever.

Comment: Baba Yaga is awesome. I love it when she shows up in my pop culture (Fables, D&D, etc)